# puppet enterprise3.7 installation validation

Tags: puppet

I have installed puppet 3.7, to validate I referred yum.log,install_log and used command puppet --version.
Is there any command to validate for successful puppet installation.

Also I would like to connect agent with puppet enterprise master. I referred puppetlab document for PE Agent,
My doubt is, to connect PE master the agent should be installed with puppet enterprise.

Please bear me if I asked anything stupidity. Because I am newbie to puppet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **very** basic form of validation using a Hello World manifest.

```
puppet apply -e 'notify { "Hello, world!": }'
```

If this runs without error, Puppet is fully functional, most likely.

I have not tried using PE at all, but I see no reason why the PE master would not work with Open Source agents. There is a REST API at the base of Puppet's network implementation after all, and I assume that the different flavors are compatible in this regards.

With that being said, the [PE FAQ](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/faq) seem to imply that your whole infrastructure should be upgraded to PE if you go that route.